# Convert pandas Series (row) to a json string

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` which I need to loop through row-wise and then, convert each row (`Series`) to a json string.

I am looping like so:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.to_json(orient='records'))
```

but the above is outputting values in a list **(without column names)**

I want to output the data in **key-value** pairs where the keys are the column name of that row element. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use `orient='index'`, your solution should be change:

```
json = {index: row.to_json(orient='index') for index, row in data.iterrows()}
```

Your loop:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    d = row.to_dict()
    print(d)
```

Or better/simplier use:

```
#for json
json = data.to_json(orient='index')

#for dictionary
d = data.to_dict(orient='index')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` function:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    a = dict(zip(df.columns, row.tolist()))
    print(a)
```

`zip` will combine the two lists element wise into a list of two values each. `dict` will then convert it to `key-value` pair where the first element in the inner list is the key and the second is the value.

Answer (score 0):

I would transform to Dict (the JSON-object equivalent in python) and loop:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1, 2], "B":[11, 22]})
for row in df.to_dict(orient='records'):
    print(row)
```

{'A': 1, 'B': 11}

{'A': 2, 'B': 22}